# Flat Json to Nested JSON - Help in JOLT

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I hv a requirement to include the record count as a header. So tried the below JOLT, but its not working

I am facing a problem, transforming a very complex JSON  Input and output detail is given below.

Input

```json
[
  {
    "Location": "A",
    "Item": "X",
    "Planning_Month": "Jan",
    "Production_Plant": "Plant1",
    "GM_M_Load_Plan_Planned_Supply": 100,
    "Total_Count": 75
  },
  {
    "Location": "B",
    "Item": "X",
    "Planning_Month": "Jan",
    "Production_Plant": "Plant1",
    "GM_M_Load_Plan_Planned_Supply": 1001,
    "Total_Count": 75
  },
  {
    "Location": "C",
    "Item": "X",
    "Planning_Month": "Jan",
    "Production_Plant": "Plant1",
    "GM_M_Load_Plan_Planned_Supply": 1001,
    "Total_Count": 75
  }
]
```

Jolt I m Using

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Total_Count": "response.Total_Count",
        "Location": "message[&1].Location",
        "Item": "message[&1].Item",
        "Planning_Month": "message[&1].Planning_Month",
        "Production_Plant": "message[&1].Production Plant",
        "W_Load_Planned_Supply": "message[&1].W Load Planned Supply"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Output Expected

```json
{
  "response": {
    "Total_Count": 75
  },
  "message": [
    {
      "Location": "A",
      "Item": "X",
      "Planning_Month": "Jan",
      "Production Plant": "Plant1"
    },
    {
      "Location": "B",
      "Item": "X",
      "Planning_Month": "Jan",
      "Production Plant": "Plant1"
    },
    {
      "Location": "C",
      "Item": "X",
      "Planning_Month": "Jan",
      "Production Plant": "Plant1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Pls help Can anyone who is a jolt expert, help me get the desired output. I think i m stuck in the last step

Comment: We will hv one Total count only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add one more spec which's of type **cardinality** stated as in the following case

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "Total_Count": "response.&",
        "Location|Item|Planning_Month": "message[&1].&",
        "P*_P*": "message[&1].P&(0,1) P&(0,2)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "response": {
        "Total_Count": "ONE"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

considering all of the objects have the identical `Total_Count` values